# A metric naturally arise from the Euclidean symplectic structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, sub-riemannian-geometry

For $n>1$ let $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n dx_i\wedge dy_i$ be the standard symplectic structure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}=\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$.
We define  the following distribution $D$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\}$:

For $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\}$ we define $D_Z=\{V\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}\mid \omega(V,Z)=0\}$

This is a nonintegrable distribution of codimension $1$. We define a meteic on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\}$ as follows: The distance $d(x,y)$ is the infimum of the Euclidean length of all $D$- horizontal curves joining(connecting) $x$ to $y$.

Is this metric  well defined(i.e. is this distribution totally non integrable)?Does this metric arise from a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\} \}$?

What about if we consider the same question but we restrict all necessary structures to $S^{2n-1}$?(Intersection of above D$ with tangent space of spher and and comoutation of length of curves on the standard geometry of sphere)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have a non-integrable distribution and a riemannian metric on a manifold. Then, one can define the metric using your construction, the resulting object is called sub-riemannian metric. It does not come from any riemannian or finslerian metric. Sub-riemannian metrics are important in the theory of nilpotent groups (and vice versa), as always with such geometric subjects there is a book of M. Gromov on it; see https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/carnot_caratheodory.pdf

It also arises in some applied area, namely, geometry of vision, on this I can not find exact reference now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very interesting answer.

Comment: Considering this applied thematic the thing to google is "sub-riemannian model of visual cortex".

Comment: thank you again for your answer. i confess that i did not read the book of Gromov yet. I just brows it but i will read it. But just a few more questions: Is the  distribution I considered totally non integrable that is the liealgebra of vector field tangent to D is thewhole algebra of vector field? Moreover is there a 1 dimensional  folition of  S^3 tangent to D(The intersection of  D with S^3) such that the foliation has no closed leaf? On the opposite extrem, is there a  1 dimensional foliation of 3 sphere tangent to D whose all leaves are closed?

Comment: Note that non of the  the three standard vector fields of  S^3, which produce foliation by circles, ,are tangent to D.

Comment: I think if you restrict codimension 1 distribution on a sphere you will obtain codimension 1 distribution. For example, consider $S^3$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4 = \mathbb{C}^2 = \mathbb{H}$. Then, the distribution $\text{Ker}(\omega(v, *))$ is also euclidean orthogonal to $I(v)$ due to the identity $\omega(v, x) = g(Iv, x)$. Now, it is actually generated by vector fields $Jv$ and $Kv$ ($I J K$ being quaternion imaginary units). Commutator of $J$ and $K$ is indeed $I$, so this distribution is non-integrable and generates the whole tangent space.

Comment: Considering similar theory for $1$-dimensional distributions they are always integrable, and so I think you can not define the similar theory for them. You can probably obtain the sequence of metrics by allowing to move transversely to the foliation but making it increasingly costly, but I'm not sure how useful this concept is.